# How to get more than 1 checkbox value to total it up in javascript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

```
var bookRate = new Array('The Right to differ', 'Issues In Contemporary Documentary', 'Writing, Directing and Producing', 'Lee Kuan Yew My Lifelong Challenge');
var selection = document.rate.checkbox;
var sum = 0.00 ;

for (i=0; i<selection.length; i++)

  if (selection[i].checked == true)
    alert('Book Name : ' + bookRate[i] + ' \n Price of the book : ' + selection[i].value )

alert('Total Purchased Books : ' + selection[i].value );
```

This what I have now.

I need to know how to total up, if there is two checkbox checked?

This function will only show the selected item.

Comment: The HTML would really help here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var bookRate=['The Right to differ', 'Issues In Contemporary Documentary', 'Writing, Directing and Producing', 'Lee Kuan Yew My Lifelong Challenge'];
var selection=document.rate.checkbox;
var books=0,sum=0.00;

for(var i=0;i<selection.length;i++)
{
    if(selection[i].checked)
    {
        books++;
        sum+=(parseFloat(selection[i].value,10) || 0);
    }
}
alert("Total purchased book: "+books+"\nTotal price: "+sum);
```

Like this?

Comment: @user1914971 I made a typo in the original answer. How about now? And please tell us what do you get if it's "not working".

Comment: The total price is incorrect. the result for total price is 0100.9099.9

Comment: the actual answer should be 200.80

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 check boxes named vehicle in my html form , like this , 
        `<form action="">
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="5" onclick="check()">vehicle 1 price<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="4" onclick="check()">vehicle 2 price
       </form>`

and my Javascript function is

```
function check()
   {
  var bookRate = new Array('The Right to differ', 'Issues In Contemporary Documentary', 'Writing, Directing and    Producing', 'Lee Kuan Yew My Lifelong Challenge');
  var selection = document.getElementsByName('vehicle');
   var sum = 0.00 ;

 for (i=0; i<selection.length; i++)
  {
  if (selection[i].checked == true)
   {
    sum=sum + parseInt(selection[i].value);

 }
 }
   alert('Total sum of  Purchased Books : ' + sum );


 }
```

Comment: what should i do to make it as double??